# Why is it a pointer to void declarator instead of a pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

The following very simple example I've written to realise the pointer to member concept:

```
struct X
{
    void f();
};

void X::*g();//error: 'g' declared as a member pointer to void

int main(){
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0aa75b4244c2be3f)**
Formally, the Standard says:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> `nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seq_opt cv-qualifier-seqopt D1`
>
> and the nested-name-specifier denotes a class, and the type of the identifier
>   in the declaration `T D1` is “`derived-declarator-type-list T`”, then the
>   type of the identifier of `D` is “derived-declarator-type-list
>   cv-qualifierseq pointer to member of class nested-name-specifier of
>   type `T`”.

Particular in my case we have:

`D1` is `g()`,

`T` is `void`,

`nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seq_opt cv-qualifier-seqopt` is `X::*`

`derived-declarator-type-list T` is `funtion returned void`

So the declaration T D must introduce a `function pointer to member of class X returnned void`.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you meant to include parentheses? `void (X::*g)();`

Comment: @remyabel Hm... it works. But could you explain the reason of my wrong? I'm trying to reason in a formal way.

Comment: A perhaps faster way to think about it (at least in relatively simple cases) is that the declarator for pointer-to-members and plain pointers work exactly the same way. So if you remove the *nested-name-specifier*, `void *g();` clearly declares a function returning a pointer to void; so with the *nested-name-specifier*, `void X::* g();` also declares a function returning a pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start your derivation correctly by assuming that `g` first binds with `()`, giving you `g()`. But that alone already means that `g` is a *function* that takes no parameters, not a pointer. At this point all chances of `g` becoming a *pointer* are gone forever. The rest of the declaration will describe the return type of the function. So, obviously, your derivation is incorrect. (If you proceed with derivation you'll arrive at the type specified in the error message).

Similar to operators, postfix parts of declaration have higher priority than prefix ones. Which means that if you want your `g` to be a pointer of any kind, you have to force your `g` to bind to `*` first. This is achieved by using `()`: `(*g)`. This would make `g` a *regular* pointer to something. If you want `g` to have a *pointer-to-member* type, you have to enclose the whole `X::*` into the parenthesis: `(X::*g)`.

Finally, to complete the declaration we make it a pointer-to-member-function that returns `void`: `void (X::*g)()`.

Comment: That's actually I declared a function returned member pointer to void, right?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv: Yes. When I run it in ideone it gives me this message: "error: cannot declare pointer to ‘void’ member". It does not refer to `g` itself. It refers to the return type of `g()`.

Comment: @Dmitry `void X::* g;` will declare a pointer to a `void` member of `X` which is invalid, because you cannot have a `void` member. `void (X::* h)();` will declare a pointer to a `void()` member of `X`.

Answer (score 2):

The last step of your derivation is in error. `g` is a "function returning a pointer to member of class `X` of type `void`". But of course there can't be a member of `X` of type `void`.